# Why am I getting the error that BAC0 has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python-3.x, iot, plc, bacnet, bac0

I am getting started with trying to retrieve information from  BACnet/IP devices. I found out that the BAC0 module in python can be used for this. These 3 lines should return information but instead, I get an error that "module BAC0 has no attribute 'connect'. But I know for sure that the BAC0 modules does have this attribute. This error also occurs when I leave the .connect() arguments list blank. What am I doing wrong? I also have bacpypes module installed and I'm using python3.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaiQq.png)

I was expecting information about BACnet devices on my network.

Comment: Could be due to the order of package installation or a conflict; I'm not a BAC0 developer nor Python developer, but I've only installed 'BAC0'; has the library not installed properly (?).

Comment: E.g.  My own sample - as yes 'connect()' was recognised:

import BAC0

BAC0.log_level('info')

#  WARNING:  Doesn't like other localhost addresses
bacnet = BAC0.lite(ip = '127.0.0.1', port = 47810)
# bacnet = BAC0.lite(ip = '192.168.1.7', port = 47810)

bacnet = BAC0.connect(ip = "127.1.2.2/8");

# value = bacnet.read("127.1.2.2:47810 analogInput 1001 presentValue")
# value = bacnet.read("195.120.128.112:47808 analogInput 1 presentValue")

print(value)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have imported the BAC0 library but you have not instantiated the class as "BACnet".

This is a programing language issue not a BACnet or BAC0 library issue

Comment: Thanks for your response! To clarify are you saying I have to first create an instance of a 'BACnet' class?? I had no idea that there was a class for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
pip install pytz
```

Simply run your python script after installing pytz library.